# Does writing to only part of a dynamically allocated memory block set the effective type of the whole block?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

EDIT: The "effective type" I am talking about is mentioned in [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6). (Thanks David C. Rankin for giving this link in your comment.)

After doing some reading, I do not completely understand the rules in C about effective type and strict aliasing. I have commented what I think is happening with effective type in the following code. For the sake of this example, please assume int and float are the same size.

```
void *memory = malloc(sizeof(int) + sizeof(float));

int *x = memory;    // x points to an "object" with no effective type.
*x = 1;             // x points to an object with effective type int.
float *y = memory;  // y points to an object with effective type int.
++y;                // y points to an "object" with effective type ???
```

At the end, y points to memory that has not yet been written to. So, it would make sense to me if y pointed to an "object" with no effective type.

On the other hand, an int has been written in the dynamically allocated "object," so this "object" might be interpreted as an array of ints. From that point of view, it would make sense to me if y pointed to an object with effective type int.

Consider another example:

```
void *memory = malloc(sizeof(short) + sizeof(float));

short *x = memory;  // x points to an "object" with no effective type.
*x = 1;             // x points to an object with effective type short.
++x;                // x points to an "object" with effective type ???
```

Here, it seems unreasonable to imagine what x points to as a float because of memory alignment. Due to alignment issues like this I could understand why writing to part of a block of memory might set the effective type of the entire block.

If that were always true, if I understand, it would technically be undefined behavior to allocate a huge block of memory and later **access** different data types on either end of it.

This is really the core issue that has led me to look into effective type. I have been using my own memory arenas, but I can't figure out whether allocating huge chunks of memory and interpreting them as consecutively packed different structures is **technically** wrong. It has consistently worked in practice. Otherwise, what is a valid way to implement the storage of more than one type within a dynamically allocated block of memory (besides putting them all in a struct or union)?

Comment: I'm not sure where you came up with this concept of "effective type" of memory that has yet to be assigned a value of _any_ type. I believe the point of strict aliasing is to avoid assigning a value one type to a particular segment of memory, and then reinterpreting that same segment as a different type. It has nothing to do (as far as I'm aware) with how you choose to partition large blocks of memory, and with what types you decide to interpret different parts as, as long as those choices are made _consistently_ for each segment.

Comment: Chuckling... [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) is clear as mud on those finer points. However in your case, you *access* `memory` which has `void*` type using pointers of `int*` and `float*`. Neither implicate §6.5 because `void*` is assignable to/from any pointer type without a cast. Now if you attempt to access `x` through `y` or vice-versa, then you implicate §6.5.

Comment: "effective type" is a property of a region of memory. In the case where you don't overlap things it's reasonably clear, but the standard has not much to offer if you, say, read from an area that's half `int` and half `float`

Comment: Writing only sets effective type of what you wrote (and, arguably, a struct that contains the member if you wrote only a struct member). It doesn't set subsequent potential array elements

Comment: no doubt supercat will be along any minute now to tell us what a quality implementation suitable for low-level programming would do

Comment: Thanks @David, I have edited my question to include your link.

Comment: @M.M, you can correct me if I've got it wrong, but since only the effective type of what has been written is set, then accessing a different part of this block of allocated memory as something else does not result in undefined behavior (as long as alignment is OK)?

Comment: @AaronFairbanks writing into malloc'd space is never UB (not for aliasing reasons anyway), and the strict aliasing rule applies to reading bytes that have previously been written as a different type

Comment: @M.M. Thanks, that's what I needed to know. However, th33lf's answer and comments imply the opposite, i.e. that if some bytes in a block have been written as one type, then due to potential type size and alignment issues, it's UB to read a (non-char) different type anywhere from the same block because you can't know the pointers "do not alias." Your explanations of strict aliasing and effective type make sense to me. From your angle, I don't see why one couldn't write code that determines the correct sizes & alignments and accesses nearby regions in a block as different types.

Comment: Right, non-overlapping regions of malloc'd space have nothing to do with each other. The answer of th33lf is wrong; the discussion of struct padding has nothing to do with the question, and after `++y` it is fine to write through `*y`  (obviously not reading through it since that is uninitialized memory at the location).

Comment: if alignment is correct, that is

Comment: @M.M > writing into malloc'd space is never UB (not for aliasing reasons anyway), and the strict aliasing rule applies to reading bytes that have previously been written as a different type< Are you sure? This: `assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int));  assert(alignof(float) == alignof(int));  void *some_mem = malloc(NO_OF_ITEMS * sizeof(float) + NO_OF_ITEMS * sizeof(int)); float *p_float = some_mem; int *p_int = (int*)(p_float + NO_OF_ITEMS);` makes gcc issue:  "...dereferencing type-punned pointer might break strict-aliasing rules..." for the last line.

Comment: @GermanNerd try posting a godbolt link; also it says "might", not "will"; and the strict aliasing rule is defined by the standard, not by gcc anyway.

Comment: @M.M Never done that....hope this works. [link](https://godbolt.org/z/y1a4Cd)

Comment: @GermanNerd it worked... the code looks correct to me and the warning is over-cautious

Comment: @M.M Added some more code - do you still think it is valid code? (I think it ought to be, but am very much in doubt due to the standard as quoted above by David. [expanded code sample](https://godbolt.org/z/d0EdJT)

Comment: @GermanNerd the section you marked as "punning" causes undefined behaviour: you wrote memory as `float` and read the same memory as `int`

Comment: @M.M Yes, I am aware of that. Just for curiosity's sake...since I know of no current architecture that has trap representations for integers, I think it is reasonably safe to do that in exploratory code. Other way round is another story, IMHO. Anyhow, apart from the punning printf? Isn't the use of p_int_alias to write the float values already UB by the strict-aliasing rule? And if so, is there any grounds other than (theoretical, for this example) compiler optimizations for it? We used to do similar things all the time back in the 80ies....Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GermanNerd writing into malloc'd space sets the *effective type* therefore it cannot be a violation.  I would never say that UB is reasonably safe. The compiler would be fully entitled to see the violation and format your hard drive or whatever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyone seeking to understand the C Standard should read the published Rationale document (available at e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf which is the first google hit for "C99 Rationale").

The ability to support the various kinds of interesting constructs that had made C uniquely useful has always been a Quality of Implementation issue, outside the jurisdiction of the Standard.  Instead, QoI issues were intended to be left to the marketplace.  Since compiler writers whose customers would need certain constructs would presumably seek to fulfill their customers' needs without regard for whether the Standard required it, there was no need to have the Standard mandate support for constructs which some programs would need but others wouldn't, nor any reason to worry about writing rules that would unambiguously address all corner cases.

The case you're asking about is one of many to which the authors of the Standard appear to have given no consideration.  Consequently, the most reasonable interpretation would be that while the Standard doesn't forbid implementations from processing such constructs nonsensically, it was not intended to particularly invite such behavior, and quality implementations that care more about whether a construct is useful than in whether it is mandated should support it.

The Effective Type rules are based on a poorly-written response to defect report 028, which was aimed at the question of whether a compiler given something like:

```
float test(float *p1, unsigned *p2)
{
  *p1 = 1.0f;
  *p2 = 0;
  return *p1;
}
```

should be required to allow for the possibility that it might be invoked by a function like:

```
float test2(void)
{
  union { float f, unsigned u} uf;
  return test2(&uf.f, &uf.u);
}
```

The response indicated, correctly, that compilers should not be required to allow for that possibility, but cited nonsensical reasoning: because the act of writing an `unsigned` to a union object and reading an `float` was Implementation-Defined behavior, consequently the act of accessing such objects through a pointer was Undefined Behavior.  No basis was given for saying that using the pointers shouldn't yield the same Implementation-Defined behavior as using the objects directly.  The implication here was that actions which wouldn't have fully-defined behavior with unions would invoke UB.

In fact, the correct response to DR #028 should have said that there is no *general* permission to access union (or even structure) members using pointers of member type, but that an access via pointer or lvalue which is recognizable as having been derived from one of a different type that could have be used to access an object should be treated, for purposes of type-access rules, as an access via the original type.  Compilers had generally accommodated most common patterns where code would derive and use pointers, but the actual mechanisms behind such accommodation varied.  Consequently, the question of when compilers should accommodate derived lvalues was left as a Quality of Implementation issue.

The Effective Type rules attempted to "clarify" the rules by codifying the response to DR #028, without noticing that it treats Implementation-Defined Behavior as Undefined Behavior without citing any basis for doing so, and it also completely fails to consider many important corner cases.  As a result, while the rules were supposedly written to "clarify" things, they in fact have the opposite effect.

From a practical perspective, clang and gcc should be treated as processing a dialect of C which does not allow any region of storage which has ever been accessed via any particular non-character type, to be reliably accessed as any other, even in cases where the Standard would allow such access.  Conversely, other compilers like icc will recognize that in cases where it can see a pointer or lvalue of one type used to form a pointer of another, operations on that pointer may affect the original object, without regard for whether the Standard would require them to notice such things.  If no particular portion of the storage within a malloc block is ever accessed via more than one type within the lifetime of the block, even clang and gcc will probably allow disjoint parts of the block to be accessed using different types.  Neither clang nor gcc, however, can reliably handle cases where a region of storage is sometimes accessed using one type and sometimes using another, even if the only pointer that will ever be used to form the object's address is converted from the old type to the new type.

Comment: Thanks. So it would even be unreliable for me to allocate a block of memory, then write and access using one type, then clear the whole block of memory, and then write and access the same memory using a different new type? Seems it's not possible to make your own memory allocator from one big memory block (one that allows freeing of memory, anyway).

Comment: I am only having trouble parsing: `that there is no general permission to access union (or even structure) members using pointers of member type, but that an access via pointer or lvalue which is recognizable as having been derived from one of a different type that could have be used to access an object should be treated, for purposes of type-access rules, as an access via the original type.` I'm reading as "We in general never have permission to access union/struct members via pointers. Casting a pointer or lvalue to a new type should still access as the original type." I don't understand.

Comment: @supercat > Neither clang nor gcc, however, can reliably handle cases where a region of storage is sometimes accessed using one type and sometimes using another,...< As long as alignment requirements are observed, I cannot think of a reason why a compiler couldn't handle **write** accesses in such scenarios; quite the opposite, I would consider that to be a given when looking at generated assembly code for memory access. It seems to me that only the strict aliasing rule combined with the definition of effective type could make such code UB. Wish there was a `#pragma nostrict_alias` in the std.

Comment: @AaronFairbanks: If `test()` were split into three functions, the first and last of which accepted a `float*`, and the second of which accepted an `unsigned*`, and which were invoked `test1a(&uf.f); test1b(&uf.i); test1c(&uf.f);` a quality compiler should be able to recognize that the invocation of `test1b` is being passed a pointer derived from the same object the pointer given to `test1a`, and that operations performed in the first function must not be re-ordered across the invocation of the second.  If the caller had taken the address of `uf.f` once at the start of the procedure, however...

Comment: ...and passed that same pointer to the first and third functions, then once the address of `uf.i` was taken, that would render the address of `uf.f` stale (unless `uf.i` was taken first, in which case taking the address of `uf.f` would render it stale).

Comment: Ah, I think I see. When a pointer or lvalue is "derived" from (i.e. due to union/struct membership it refers to the same memory address as) another pointer or lvalue that could have accessed something, the compiler should refrain from re-ordering/optimizing in the same way it would refrain if the derived pointer were the original pointer's type. To clarify: if the address `&uf.f` is taken before `&uf.i`, then `&uf.i` is "derived" from `&uf.f`, but `&uf.i` is NOT "derived" from `&uf.f`. Am I getting what you're saying?

Comment: How flexible is your use of the word "derived"? Outside of a union, do you consider an int pointer directly casted from a float pointer "derived" from the float pointer? Lastly, what is meant by `there is no general permission to access union (or even structure) members using pointers of member type`? Now I am understanding it as "In some cases it is UB to access a union/struct member via a pointer" i.e. it is UB once a pointer becomes "stale," as you described. Is this what you mean? Thank you. I will mark this the accepted answer once I am sure I understand it.

Comment: `Neither clang nor gcc, however, can reliably handle cases where a region of storage is sometimes accessed using one type and sometimes using another, even if the only pointer that will ever be used to form the object's address is converted from the old type to the new type.` I think this implies clang and gcc respect neither the effective type rules (assuming the new type was written before being read) nor your preferred alternative rule.

Comment: @AaronFairbanks: Correct.  If the Standard doesn't specify a useful corner case, the compiler should ignore it, and if the Standard specifies a corner case that's useless, the compiler should ignore that too.

Comment: @supercat I am marking this accepted, although I still am not entirely clear on the exact meaning of "derived" in your preferred alternative rule. (See above comments.) If you have the time to explain it I'm interested. I understand enough to continue programming and it's not necessary for me to know that detail. This has been very helpful--thanks for your time.

Comment: @AaronFairbanks: By "derived", I mean essentially the concept that the Standard calls "based on" in its description of `restrict`, though the Standard's definition botches some corner cases so as to create needless ambiguity as well as crazy false-positives (e.g. by the Standard's definition, the pointer value `p1==&someStaticObject ? p2: p3` would be "based on" p1 if `p2` and `p3` differ), but within `if (p4 == &someStaticObject)`, it's ambiguous whether *any* pointer value (even `p4`(!)) is based on `p4`.

Answer (score -2):

I am still struggling with the basis of your question, but here goes anyway..

First of all `sizeof(int) + sizeof(float)` is where the problem starts. This is a promise you cannot keep! If you declare say:

```
struct t
{
    int x;
    float y;
};
```

Can you be sure that `sizeof(struct t) ==  sizeof(int) + sizeof(float)` all the time?
You obviously can't because it all depends on the alignment restrictions of the specific platform you are on. You may not be allocating enough storage for both. So if you want to store an int and a float contiguously and access them directly via pointers of the respective types, then you need to wrap them in a struct and use the size of that type.

In your case, since you know the sizes to be the same, you can always argue that it works, but this is not guaranteed by the standard.

Secondly,

```
float *y = memory;  // y points to an object with effective type int.
++y;                // y points to an "object" with effective type ???
```

is clearly undefined behaviour (the moment you try to dereference y) because you cannot be sure x and y do not alias. You cannot do pointer arithmetic unless you know you have a homogeneous array of the same type. The exception is probably char*, which you can use to directly peek into memory that belongs to any type. Again, if the sizes and alignment are the same, this might work but the language does not allow it.

> Otherwise, what is a valid way to implement the storage of more than
>   one type within a dynamically allocated block of memory (besides
>   putting them all in a struct or union)?

Treat the chunk of memory as a char array and read or write a single type at a time, using memcpy to copy to and from a temp variable with the correct effective type. Use that variable for any arithmetic operations. Otherwise you are relying on special fairy-dust that may be available only on your hardware!

Comment: 1. `So if you want to store an int and a float contiguously then you need to wrap them in a struct and use the size of that type.` - but if the alignment restrictions are ok? What if `sizeoff(struct t) = sizeof(int) + sizeof(float)`? What if all `alignof(float) == alignof(int) == sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)` ? Is the code ok then? Can we `*y = 1.0f`? 2. `is clearly undefined behaviour.` No. `You cannot do pointer arithmetic` No. You can. There is nothing wrong with incrementing `y` pointer.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk I would go one step further: The OP stated that (for the sake of the sample code) int and float *do* have the same size. AFAIK, that implies that both types' alignment requirements would be the same. If both prerequisites are satisfied, I see nothing wrong (except obfucsation of code) to access that chunk of memory with both types, or to perform the corresponding pointer arithmetic.

Comment: If the sizes are identical and alignment restrictions match and all the stars and planets are in the right position then it might work. That still doesn't make it right! It might work on an x86 and fail on an ARM, for eg.. And yes, pointer arithmetic outside of a homogeneous array is undefined behavior. Again, it might work for a particular alignment and type size, but is not guaranteed by the standard. A different compiler can give different results and you will only have yourself to blame!

Comment: @GermanNerd The OP also said that he is trying to understand the 'rules in C'. I was trying to talk about those rules here. His example invokes undefined behaviour according to the rules of the C standard.

Comment: @th33lf Your intention of pointing the OP in the correct way is laudable. However, the OP's code is not UB per se. No need for planets & stars lining up; sizeof and alignof can be used to establish correctness of the access into the malloced memory. (which is *not* an array, just a chunk of contiguous memory) Of course, what the OP tries to do here goes into the direction of recreating a struct - and why not. Very, very educational. Just don't do it in production code.

Comment: Glad we agree on the 'not to be done in production code' part. Of course, the code snippets the OP has written, are not 'technically' UB yet. But what he intends to do, however, is! Guess that was not clear from my explanation. I will also add some clarifications to my answer.

Comment: @th33lf It you edit your answer, please do not just change things, but make obsolete parts strike-through. That way, people can still follow the discussion in the comments.

Comment: OK, say I had written:

`int *x = memory; *x = 1; char *y = memory; y += sizeof(int); float z = *((float*)y);`

Is this undefined behavior? If so, why? Possible misalignment? If I were to write more code that corrects alignment, would it be undefined behavior? I understand that misalignments lead to undefined behavior, but my confusion is whether accessing two types in one block of memory violates the rules of "effective type" laid out in [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,6)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6). (Thanks David C. Rankin for giving this link in your comment.)

Comment: `Again, if the sizes and alignment are the same, this might work but the language does not allow it.` - This part of your answer makes me think that it _is_ undefined behavior, but I'm wondering what rule it violates.

Comment: Thanks for your time. My confusion is that @GermanNerd 's words imply to me that what I'm trying to do is not UB, but your words imply to me that what I'm trying to do is UB, or "not 'technically' UB yet," but about to be. I agree with all that you've said about alignment and size. Failure to use correct alignment can result in UB. I would like to talk about circumstances in which the correct alignments and sizes have been determined. Like GermanNerd said, sizeof (and alignof) can be used to establish that indeed int and float are the same size (and have the same alignment).

Comment: @AaronFairbanks Hmmm...I think a language lawyer is needed here. It does appear that having a malloced block of memory with 2 pointers of different type, *which do not and never will point to the same address* still is regarded as a violation of the strict-aliasing rule and type-punning (Via the 'effective type' definition). If this is so, I would consider the strict-aliasing rule as severely broken. In any case, that rule mainly serves compiler optimizations; the price for that is the introduction of possible 'error' sources that the compiler might not even catch.

Comment: Interesting comment on the strict-aliasing rule: https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1307

Comment: @GermanNerd `having a malloced block of memory with 2 pointers of different type, which do not and never will point to the same address still is regarded as a violation of the strict-aliasing rule` What makes you say so? As far as I can tell, the effective type rule just says you cannot read something that has been previously written to be one type as another type (with the exception of char). Here's the confusion: is writing to only part of a dynamically allocated memory block considered, by effective type rules, writing the whole block as that type? That's basically the title of my question.

Comment: @GermanNerd Thanks for posting the link to that article--interesting read. Based on my current idea of effective type, I can see why all the code listed in the article is broken, UB. However, I don't think the article clears anything up about my particular issue, in which the pointers point to non-overlapping parts of dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @AaronFairbanks I find myself as confused as you do. This is the reason for my confusion: [C11.3.15-1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15). This definition of 'object' seems to imply the whole region of dynamically allocated memory gets an effective type once even a single value is written to it as a specific type. But I might be completely wrong...Where is Supercat???? ;)

Comment: @GermanNerd: The notion of Effective Type stems from a failure to recognize that the type-access rules were only meant to apply in situations involving lvalues with no apparent relationship between them.  Given `struct s {int x[5];} foo; int *p;`, a compiler given `int test(void) { foo.x[0] = 1; *p = 2; return foo.x[0];}` should be entitled to assume that nothing will access `foo.x[0]` between the assignment and the return, since nothing in the code between those refers to anything of type `struct s`, nor member `x` of a `struct s`.  On the other hand, any decent compiler given...

Comment: `int test(int i) { foo.x[0] = 1; p = foo.x+i; *p = 2; return foo.x[0];}` should refrain from trying to cache `foo.x[0]`, since the address of `foo.x` is taken between the write to `foo.x[0]` and the later read, and code performs a store via the pointer formed thereby.

Comment: @supercat > Given struct s {int x[5];} foo; int *p;, a compiler given int test(void) { foo.x[0] = 1; *p = 2; return foo.x[0];} should be entitled to assume that nothing will access foo.x[0] between the assignment and the return,...< I think that is a dangerous assumption and an invitation for errors. Why not leave that decision to the programmer, like with the restrict qualifier?

Comment: @GermanNerd: Supporting some existing programs would require modes that disable various optimizations, but code which is going to use a pointer to access a seemingly-unrelated containing object should indicate that it's going to do something as useful, either using a `volatile` qualifier or a not-yet-invented more narrowly targeted version.  The `volatile` qualifier shouldn't be required on both aliased objects, but should be taken as a warning to the compiler that an access to an object might interact with other objects in ways a compiler may not understand.

Comment: @supercat That might be a way (although I think that `volatile` is too much of a barrier to what the compiler may do), but I feel that something is fundamentally wrong if instead of reasoning about the abstract machine programmers have to reason about **possible and unknown** optimizations by compilers. Classifying some uses of the C language's capabilities as UB (and the strict aliasing rule seems to do just that) for the only purpose of giving compiler implementations more latitude seems to run against the spirit of C, IMHO.

Comment: Just back after the weekend and surprised at all the downvotes! Does my answer contribute negatively to the solution? If I could summarize, the code is UB due to 3 reasons: alignment, type-size and aliasing! Any one would have been sufficient. UB is always UB - you cannot qualify it with "if type-sizes are the same" or "if the architecture is ARM". It is because of what is in the specs and has nothing to do with actual implementation details!

Comment: @th33lf I guess it is because your answer mainly addresses questions the OP did not ask. The only thing he is (understandably) confused about is whether a malloced block of memory constitutes an 'object' which's effective type is set as a whole when first assigning it a value of a specific type. He did not ask about sizes or alignment, which can be controlled for, thereby avoiding UB. But that is the part your answer focuses on. So it is largely off-topic. Also, there are wrong statements in your answer, like the alleged inability to do pointer arithmetic except inside a typed array.

Comment: @GermanNerd: Oh right, **wrong** statements like that one! How about this statement from the C11 standard (on pointer arithmetic, emphasis added): "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**" Pointer arithmetic outside of a typed array is meaningless. You cannot de-reference that pointer!

Comment: @GermanNerd Just for context, it also states: _"For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."_ And, _"If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated"._

Comment: @th33lf, again, please don't change/add to anything that already has answers/comments. It can make the whole thread worthless.

Comment: @GermanNerd I did not change anything since last my last comment 2 days ago. Even before that, all I did was add clarifications. I agree with everything you guys said, and I have myself up-voted supercat's obviously better answer (which wasn't there at the time). I was merely contesting the claim that I made wrong claims, which so far, I do not agree with. Of course, I would be glad to be proven wrong, if some new learning comes out of it. But please try not to work under an implicit assumption that just because someone is new, everything they say is wrong!

Comment: @GermanNerd I agree, of course the standard could have been a lot clearer on things like this. Which is why, these kinds of questions lead to unending debates and exotic interpretations. With this question, "Treat the chunk of memory as a char array and read or write a single type at a time, using memcpy to copy to and from a temp variable with the correct effective type" -- is what I thought was the solution he was seeking, but understood only later that what he was looking for was more of a reason why his approach is wrong, which I admit I wasn't able to figure out until read supercat!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197491/discussion-between-germannerd-and-th33lf).